# Request : duplicateSheet with Google Spreadsheet API : badRequest: Must specify at least one request

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to duplicate a sheet using Google Spreadsheet API.
But I keep getting this error : badRequest: Must specify at least one request

I've tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work so far.

Here is what I have (ruby) :

```
request_body = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.new {
  {
  "includeSpreadsheetInResponse": false,
  "requests": [
    {
      "duplicateSheet": {
        "sourceSheetId": 1*********,
        "insertSheetIndex": 2,
        "newSheetId": 10,
        "newSheetName": "*********"
      }
    }
  ],
  "responseIncludeGridData": false,
  "responseRanges": [
    ""
  ]}
}

response = service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, request_body)
```

I know the code is not over but I really can't figure out what is missing

Does anyone know what I need ? Many thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

The `new` object should be enclosed with open and close parenthesis.

Your code should look like this:

```
request_body = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.new(
  {
  "includeSpreadsheetInResponse": false,
  "requests": [
    {
      "duplicateSheet": {
        "sourceSheetId": 1*********,
        "insertSheetIndex": 2,
        "newSheetId": 10,
        "newSheetName": "*********"
      }
    }
  ],
  "responseIncludeGridData": false,
  "responseRanges": [
    ""
  ]}
)
```

**Reference:**

- [Ruby Object and Classes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_classes.htm#:%7E:text=You%20can%20create%20objects%20in,belongs%20to%20the%20class%20methods.&text=Here%2C%20cust1%20and%20cust2%20are%20the%20names%20of%20two%20objects.)

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you use the camel case. In the case of Ruby, please use the snake case as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
request_body = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.new(
{
  include_spreadsheet_in_response: false,
  requests: [
    {
      duplicate_sheet: {
        source_sheet_id: 1*********,
        insert_sheet_index: 2,
        new_sheet_id: 10,
        new_sheet_name: "*********",
      }
    }
  ],
  response_include_grid_data: false,
  response_ranges: [""]
})
response = service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, request_body)
```

#### Note:

- As other patterns, you can also use the following scripts.

  - Pattern 2

    ```
      request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::Request.new
      request.duplicate_sheet = {
        source_sheet_id: 1*********,
        insert_sheet_index: 2,
        new_sheet_id: 10,
        new_sheet_name: "*********",
      }
      request_body = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.new
      request_body.include_spreadsheet_in_response = false
      request_body.response_include_grid_data = false
      request_body.response_ranges = [""]
      request_body.requests = [request]
      response = service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, request_body)
    ```
  - Pattern 3

    ```
      request_body = {
        include_spreadsheet_in_response: false,
        requests: [{duplicate_sheet: {
          source_sheet_id: 1*********,
          insert_sheet_index: 2,
          new_sheet_id: 10,
          new_sheet_name: "*********",
        }}],
        response_include_grid_data: false,
        response_ranges: [""],
      }
      response = service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, request_body, {})
    ```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that your `service` can be used for using the batchUpdate method. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)